# Checking wait_for in Ansible in a particular host group does not work

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook similar to

```
  ---
  - name: testplaybook
  hosts:
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
     -role: samplerole
```

role:

```
 - name: checking for port open
   wait-for: 
      timeout: 3
      host: groups['git_groups']
      port: 7809
      ignore_error: yes
      register: port_check
```

For the above code the host: `groups['git_groups']` doesn't work as an input here. When I run the playbook, it checks for the entire lists of hosts rather than that particular group.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot feed an arbitrary data structure (list in your case) to an argument of a module which requires a string (“[A resolvable hostname or IP address to wait for](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/wait_for_module.html)”).

You should use a [`with_items` loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html):

```
- name: checking for port open
  wait_for: 
    timeout: 3
    host: "{{ item }}"
    port: 7809
  ignore_error: yes
  register: port_check
  with_items: "{{ groups['git_groups'] }}"
```

<sup>You also have two of your task directives wrongly indented.</sup>