# How to use Ansible module 'wait_for' together with 'loop'?

Tags: python, list, loops, ansible

In Ansible 2.7.11 and wanted to use the module [waif_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) together with [loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) for connection test to my System Center Operations Manager (SCOM) servers.

Currently I'm using a task

```yaml
- name: "Test connection to SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD: {{ SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD }}"
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ item }}"
    port: "{{ SCOM_PORT }}"
    state: drained         # Port should be open
    delay: 0               # No wait before first check (sec)
    timeout: 3             # Stop checking after timeout (sec)
    active_connection_states: SYN_RECV
  with_items:
    - server1
    - server2
    - server3
    - server4
  ignore_errors: yes
  tags: connectionTest,testSCOM
```

where the variable `SCOM_PORT` is set to `1270` and `SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD` to a list of servers `"server1,server2,server3,server4"`.

This approach is working but I wanted to have a variable list of servers maintained at a central place, like a global variable `SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD` in inventory file.

It is possible to iterate over such a list via

```yaml
- debug:
    msg="{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ [SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD] }}"
```

but when using this approach in the task

```yaml
- name: "Test connection to SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD: {{ SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD }}"
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ item }}"
    port: "{{ SCOM_PORT }}"
    state: drained         # Port should be open
    delay: 0               # No wait before first check (sec)
    timeout: 3             # Stop checking after timeout (sec)
    active_connection_states: SYN_RECV
  loop: "{{ [SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD] }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  tags: connectionTest,testSCOM
```

I'm getting an error

```json
failed: [host] (item=server1,server2,server3,server4) => ... /tmp/ansible_wait_for_payload_zNj2ac/__main__.py\", line 380, in _convert_host_to_hex\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_wait_for_payload_zNj2ac/__main__.py\", line 354, in _convert_host_to_ip\r\nsocket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

which for me indicates that the module `wait_for` got the full list as item instead of one server from the list. The reason for the described behavior seems to be answered @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351187/.

Any idea how to get the module `wait_for` working with a variable list of servers?

**Other Components**

- RHEL 7.6
- `python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 12:19:05) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]`
- Module [dig](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dig.html) is installed, but not used since it doesn't change the behavior together with [lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with colleagues it turned out that the list (of servers) wasn't defined correctly in inventory, just a classical syntax error. Please see [Ansible, how to define a list in host inventory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149975/ansible-how-to-define-a-list-in-host-inventory).

To get it working it is necessary to define in inventory file the variable as

```ini
SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD="['server1','server2','server3','server4']"
```

instead of an just comma separated list of strings and use for loop

```yaml
loop: "{{ SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD }}"
```

By doing this I've realized that actually the debug message wasn't iterating over the list either. Now it is working properly

```json
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host] => (item=server1) => {
    "msg": "server1"
}
ok: [host] => (item=server2) => {
    "msg": "server2"
}
ok: [host] => (item=server3) => {
    "msg": "server3"
}
ok: [host] => (item=server4) => {
    "msg": "server4"
}

TASK [Test connection to SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD: ['server1','server2','server3','server4']] ***
ok: [host] => (item=server1)
ok: [host] => (item=server2)
ok: [host] => (item=server3)
ok: [host] => (item=server4)
```

---

Meanwhile I've found out also that it is possible to [Looping over inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-inventory) and if I use

```yaml
with_items: "{{ groups['SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD'] }}"
```

together with a group in inventory file

```ini
[SCOM_MGMT_SRV_PROD]
server1
server2
server3
server4
```

Since the monitoring servers are not part of infrastructure which is maintained by Ansible, Linux admins, etc., I do not like to include them in the inventory other than in a variable.

Are there any other options to loop over a variable list of servers? ... if not, it might be necessary to go with this as solution.